# What does invalid initializer mean?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, initialization, dynamic-memory-allocation

Having this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 5

int main()
{
    //int (*ar)[10] = malloc(sizeof *ar * SIZE);
    int *ar[10] = malloc(sizeof *ar * SIZE);
    printf("%ld\n", sizeof *ar);
}
```

I got

```
a.c:8:19: error: invalid initializer
    8 |     int *ar[10] = malloc(sizeof *ar * SIZE);
      |
```

Why is this pointer initialization uses "invalid initializer"? What is invalid here?

Comment: It's so invalid I have no idea what you're even trying to achieve.  `int *ar[10] = { malloc(sizeof *ar * SIZE) };` would initialize `a[0]` with the result of `malloc`, and the remainder of the elements with `NULL`, but that doesn't seem like a sensible thing to do.

Comment: @ikegami were it `(*ar)[10] = ...` (the only change is adding parethesis) is no more "so invalid".

Comment: @ikegami: Once parentheses are placed around `*ar`, the code is not invalid. Alternately, removing `[10]` renders the code valid. Both of these are “one step” changes that are quite apparent.

Comment: @ikegami: `int (*ar)[10] = malloc(sizeof *ar * SIZE);` allocates space for `SIZE` (which is 5 as shown) arrays of 10 `int`, a.k.a. a 5×10 matrix of `int`, and it makes `ar` point to the first of those, so `ar[i][j]` would index an element in the 5×10 matrix. `int *ar = malloc(sizeof *ar * SIZE);` would allocate space for `SIZE` `int`. Each of these makes sense by itself, although the `10` in the original code with the context of `SIZE` being 5 points toward the former as being intended.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil , ack, yes, comments deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like `3+(4*5)` is completely different than `(3+4)*5`,

```c
int *(x[10]);    // int *x[10];
```

is completely different than

```c
int (*x)[10];
```

---

The following creates an array of 10 pointers:

```c
int *ar[10];
```

Arrays are initialized using `{ }`.<sup>[1]</sup> For example, you could use the following:

```c
int *ar[10] = {
   NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
   NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
};
```

But in this case, you might use something like this:

```c
int *ar[10];

for (int i=10; i--; ) {
   ar[i] = malloc(sizeof(*ar));
   *(ar[i]) = 0;
}
```

This produces the following:

```
                          +---------------+    sizeof( ar       ) == sizeof( int * ) * 10
ar                   +--->| 0             |    sizeof( ar[0]    ) == sizeof( int * )
+---------------+    |    +---------------+    sizeof( *(ar[0]) ) == sizeof( int   )
|             -------+
+---------------+
|             -------+
+---------------+    |    +---------------+
|               |    +--->| 0             |
       ...                +---------------+
|               |
+---------------+
```

---

The following creates a (single) pointer to an array of 10 pointers.

```c
int (*p)[10];
```

It could be allocated as follows:

```
int (*p)[10] = malloc(sizeof(*p));

for (int i=10; i--; )
   (*p)[i] = 0;
```

This produces the following:

```
p
+---------------+         +---------------+    sizeof( p       ) == sizeof( int * )
|             ----------->| 0             |    sizeof( *p      ) == sizeof( int * ) * 10
+---------------+         +---------------+    sizeof( (*p)[0] ) == sizeof( int   )
                          | 0             |
                          +---------------+
                          |               |
                                 ...       
                          |               |
                          +---------------+
```

---

1. Special case,

   ```c
   char s[] = "abc";
   ```

   is a shorthand for

   ```c
   char s[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 0 };
   ```

Comment: Fixed some errors and rearranged stuff

Comment: Thanks for graphical representation. So could I imagine the `int(*ar)[10]` -> double array as continous array? (As opposed to array of pointers)

Comment: @milanHrabos yes, `p` could be a pointer to the first of many, just like `char*` could be a pointer to the first of many. Same goes for `ar[i]`. In C, the type of doesn't indicate if a pointer points to one or just the first of many.

Answer (score 1):

You declared an array of 10 elements of the type `int *`

```
int *ar[10] = malloc(sizeof *ar * SIZE);
```

and trying to initialize the array with the expression `malloc(sizeof *ar * SIZE)`. So the compiler issues the error message.

If you want to dynamically allocate an array with `SIZE` elements of the type `char[10]` then you need to write

```
int ( *ar )[10] = malloc( SIZE * sizeof( char[10] ) );
```

To make the declaration of the pointer simpler you could introduce a typedef declaration for the array of 10 elements. For example

```
typedef int TArray[10];
TArray *ar = malloc( SIZE * sizeof( TArray ) );
```

Pay attention to that you need to use the conversion specifier `%zu` to output objects of the type `size_t` (it is the type of the value returned by the operator `sizeof`). For example

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof *ar);
```

This call will output the value equal to `10 * sizeof( int )`. If the `sizeof( int )` is equal to `4` then the outputted value will be `40`.

Comment: So the first case is array for 10 pointers. So why with just adding the parenthesis, the meaning is completely change to something different?

Comment: @milanHrabos This declaration int ( *ar )[10] declares a pointer to an array of 10 elements. You could write typedef int TArray[10]; and then TArray *ar; That makes the declaration of the pointer simpler.

Comment: @milanHrabos, Re "*the meaning is completely change to something different?*", Yes, `int *ar[10]` aka `int *(ar[10)]` is an array of 10 pointers to ints, and `int (*ar)[10]` is a pointer to an array of 10 ints.

Comment: @milanHrabos yes.   for example `10+5 *3` means something different than `(10+5)*3`

Answer (score 0):

```
int *ar[10];
```

Is an array of 10 pointers to `int`. You need a pointer (not array) to dynamically allocate memory for the referencceod object.

Depending on type of the pointer you can:

```
int *ar = malloc(sizeof *ar * SIZE);   // space for SZIE integers
int **ar = malloc(sizeof *ar * SIZE);  // space for SIZE pointer to integers
int (*ar)[10] = malloc(sizeof *ar * SIZE); // space for SIZE * 10 integers, but pointer type is array to 10 integers/
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this pointer initialization uses "invalid initializer"? What is invalid here?

`int *ar[10]` does not declare a pointer. It declares an array. Initializers for an array should be inside braces, `{ … }`, so `malloc(sizeof *ar * SIZE)` is not valid to initialize an array.

Brackets, `[ … ]` bind more tightly than the dereference operator, `*`, so `int *ar[10]` is `int *(ar[10])`, making an array of pointers. To make a pointer to an array, you must use `int (*ar)[10]`, as shown in your first declaration.

Answer (score 0):

you should use :
Also you are using wrong syntex for sizeof.

```
// pointer to an array of five numbers
 int (* ar)[10] = NULL;

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 5

int main(){
    int *ar = malloc(sizeof(int) * SIZE);
    printf("%ld", sizeof(ar));
    return 0;
}
```